# how do i make my rendered cards responsive?

Tags: reactjs, responsive, antd

I am trying to make my cards responsive when my screen resize. I have tried using Row and col from antd but it is not working.

Below image shows the cards are being squeeze when the resolution is smaller
[image]

Below image shows What I actually expect, cards to align nicely in one column when resolution is smaller

[image]

Below is my code

```
const [customCard] = useState(defaultCardsInfo);
  let columnStyle = {
    float: "left",
    width: "30%",
    padding: "5px",
    position: "relative"
  };
  const [column] = useState(columnStyle);

  const renderCards = () => {
    return customCard.slice(0, 6).map((item, i) => (
      <div key={i} style={column}>
        <Row gutter={16}>
          <Col xs={24} xl={8}>
            <Card title="Card title" bordered={true}>
              Card content
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <br />
      </div>
    ));
  };
```

This is my codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/responsive-form-f110d?file=/App.js), any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have solve it. I use @media to change my width to 100% when reach certain resolution.

Below are my codes

```
...
<div className='hello' key={i} style={column}>
   <Row gutter={16}>
     <Col xs={24} xl={8}>
       <Card title="Card title" bordered={true}>
          Card content
       </Card>
     </Col>
   </Row>
   <br />
</div>
...
```

my css. Adjust the value accordingly

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .hello {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}
```

Hope this help someone in the future